# Deleting WordPress posts in front-end with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to remove WordPress posts from front end using AJAX.
My code removes post, but displays blank page with "success", when i want to just fade out this post without page reloading and displaying blank page.

PHP code:

```
<?php if( current_user_can( 'delete_post' ) ) : ?>
        <?php $nonce = wp_create_nonce('my_delete_post_nonce') ?>
        <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=my_delete_post&id=' . get_the_ID() . '&nonce=' . $nonce ) ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID() ?>" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" class="delete-post">delete</a>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Functions.php code:

```
function my_frontend_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_frontend_script' );
wp_localize_script( 'js/my_script.js', 'MyAjax2', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'ajaxnonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce') ) );


add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_delete_post', 'my_delete_post' );
function my_delete_post(){

    $permission = check_ajax_referer( 'my_delete_post_nonce', 'nonce', false );
    if( $permission == false ) {
        echo 'error';
    }
    else {
        wp_delete_post( $_REQUEST['id'] );
        echo 'success';
    }

    die();
}
```

my_script.js code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    $(document).on( 'click', '.delete-post', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var nonce = $(this).data('nonce');
        var post = $(this).parents('.post:first');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: MyAjax2.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'my_delete_post',
                nonce: nonce,
                id: id
            },
            success: function( result ) {
                if( result == 'success7' ) {
                    post.fadeOut( function(){
                        post.remove();
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
})
```

The problem is page is reloading to a blank page with "success" text, when it should just fade out and remove post from current page, without reloading.

It looks like my_script.js is not even used at all :(

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=my_delete_post&id=' . get_the_ID() . '&nonce=' . $nonce ) ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID() ?>" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" class="delete-post">delete</a>
```

it's reloading because it loads first the url in your href attribute, then executing your ajax-call. thats not what you want. you want to execute only the onclick. this should solve the problem. just put a # in your href

```
<a href=# data-id="<?php the_ID() ?>" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" class="delete-post">delete</a>
```

or make buttons

```
<button data-id="<?php the_ID() ?>" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" class="delete-post">delete</button>
```

edit: if it's still not working, it's because you got a typo here

```
if( result == 'success7' )
```

success7 instead of success

Comment: Unfortunately, using # or making a button does nothing ;/ After clicking on link or button nothing happens...Any idea why?

Comment: it should work. look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/k8y1ucor/2/

also, the fact that you got an "empty" page with "success" tells me, that in general your ajax function is working.

i think now it's just a typo:  if( result == 'success7' )  
success7 instead of success